# Accessing Json object values with the Help of a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I've a huge json file which has a lot of nested key value pairs. So I thought I should save the keys as dictionary values and use that dictionary values as keys to access the values from the json file. Say for example:

```
json_obj = {
 "calendar" :{
    "day": {
      "activities" : {
         "morning:"walk"
       }
     }
  }
}
```

so I thought to access the key `morning` value, instead of writing

```
json_obj['calendar']['day']['activities']['morning']
```

I should keep a **dictionary** which will contain the query parameters like

```
query_parameters = {
 0 :[['calendar'],['day'],['activities'],['morning']]
}
```

And use this dictionary to query from the json object. 
But

> Here is my question? 
> Can I use this dictionary to write query or to access values from my json_obj without using any loops ? 
> say something like `json_obj[query_parameters[0]]` # this is not right syntax I know 
> Or do you have any suggestions when accessing these long key value pair from an object?

Comment: yeah it's possible but you need to write some custome function, dirctly you can't access

Comment: @deadshot can u elaborate please

Comment: you can't directly access dictionary value with `query_parameters` but you can write some function that can convert the queryparameters to dictionary keys and get the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function like this
This function will return value if exist otherwise returns `None`

```
def fun(query, data):
    if not query:
        return data
    if query[0][0] in data:
        return fun(query[1:], data[query[0][0]])

print(fun(query_parameters[0], json_obj)) # walk
```